# Js lodash return the same sample every time

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I want to generate samples with lodash and it return me the same numbers for each line. what im doing wrong?

```
var primaryNumsCells = _.range(50);
var extraNumsCells = _.range(20);

var lottery = {lineConfigurations: []};


var numsConfig = {lineNumbers: {}};

    for( var i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {

      numsConfig.lineNumbers.primaryNumbers = _.sample(primaryNumsCells, 5);
      numsConfig.lineNumbers.secondaryNumbers = _.sample(extraNumsCells, 2);
      lottery.lineConfigurations.push(numsConfig);
    }

console.log(lottery);
```

The results of the first object and second object of the primary and secondary numbers is the same;

here is the fiddle:
 http://jsbin.com/vavuhunupi/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *new* object inside a loop. It's easy to do with a plain object literal (dropping the variable):

```
var lottery = {lineConfigurations: []};
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  lottery.lineConfigurations.push({
    lineNumbers: {
      primaryNumbers: _.sample(primaryNumsCells, 5),
      secondaryNumbers: _.sample(extraNumsCells, 2)
    }
  });
}
```

As it stands, at each step of the loop you modify and push *the same object* (stored in `numsConfig` var).

---

And here goes a lodash way of doing the same thing:

```
var lottery = {
  lineConfigurations: _.map(_.range(2), function() {
    return {
      lineNumbers: {
        primaryNumbers: _.sample(primaryNumsCells, 5),
        secondaryNumbers: _.sample(extraNumsCells, 2)
      }
    };
  })
};
```

Comment: Great it is working, thanks, i will mark this as answer when i can :)